# Prevent a Jenkins build caused by git push in same job

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have written a Jenkinsfile for use in a GitHub Organization object in Jenkins. Part of the Jenkinsfile is error correcting, and often makes changes to the project. At the end of the pipeline, Jenkins commits the changes to our git repository.

Now that I have all of this working, I have realized that upon pushing the corrections to the repo, the same job that just ran and corrected the errors will run again, since it is triggered by webhooks. It wouldn't be an infinite loop because there would be no errors to correct after running the first time, but it would run one more time than it needs to.

The fact that the changes made by the job end up triggering the job is problematic because the pipeline includes a deploy step. Redeploying the same code twice in a row feels like the result of a poorly written pipeline. That said, short of searching the last commit message for keywords, I cannot figure out a good way to make commits from the job not trigger the job. Is there a less hacky way to solve this problem?

edit: I am aware of the ci-skip plugin, but I can't documentation for making it work in a declarative pipeline. I would prefer an approach that lets me do something with the default scm checkout step at the start of the build.

edit 2: I ended up just running a grep of the last commit message everytime the pipeline starts to see if the message contained the text [ci skip]. Its dirty, but it works if its placed in a setup stage of the pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

In the configuration to checkout a git repo, you can specify there to ignore certain commit messages (advanced checkout behavior) Rather than using code to do it. However, I'm not sure if if a github org job can do the same thing.

Another option would be to ignore certain directories if the changes are confined to certain directories, and those directories aren't normally changes otherwise. Again, not sure if github org supports this.

Don't use webhook triggeers, possibly, but this isn't a preferred option.

Comment: Sadly, there is no job level configuration in this type. It just scans all of the repos in an org, and for any with a Jenkinsfile, it sets up a job according to that (declarative) Jenkinsfile.